# scoping on parallel thread in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have 4 distinct large files I'd like to load into memory simultaneously. The following example is not exactly what I'm doing -- but it illustrates to problem:

```
matlabpool open local 4
spmd
    if labindex==1 
        R = rand(9,9);
      else
        R = rand(4,4);
    end
end
size(R)
```

when I copy and paste this into the command prompt, R pops up in my work space. but if i save this to a *.m file, size(R) doesn't evaluate -- it gives me an error that R doesn't exist. I've tried using gather and initializing R as a global to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean `R` pops up? You have a semicolon after the lines where `R` is created. I can't replicate what you describe (Matlab R2012b, OS X 10.8.3). The code above runs normally from the command window, a script M-file, and a function M-file. `size(R)` prints out every time: a 1-by-4 composite. Did you possibly create a function M-file rather than a script and are trying to access `R` from the command window after running the file? If it was a function then you're right, it is a scoping issue. Functions have their own scope regardless of if they call `spmd` or not.

Comment: okay -- I just figured out what was happening. see below

Answer (score 0):

Okay:

I was saving this script as test.m.

Then I was calling it from the command line as:
    run test.m

But then I ran it as-is from command line: test

'run' must spawn a subprocess which it kills after running or something. this must have been killing the variables. just calling the script straight correctly shares the scope of the workspace with the script.